# Rookie Oracle Variable Question

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a simple SQL Statement that works perfectly in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @ID VARCHAR(10)
SET @ID = '12345'

SELECT *
FROM theTable 
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Can someone please tell me how to do this extremely basic thing in Oracle?

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I chose ropstah's answer because his was the first that I could make work for me.  Nothing personal guys, but man is it hard to do some stuff in Oracle

Comment: Keep at it, wcm, Oracle has a steep learning curve - but it's worth it - there's a lot of power available when you master it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to set the variables at the top of the script maybe this is your solution?

```
with IDS as (
    select 1234 from dual
    union all
    select 1235 from dual
)

select * from TABLE where TABLE.ID in (select * from IDS)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ropstah!  I think that the other answers would have worked for me if I knew more Oracle but this is the first that I could get to return some results.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar using the SQL*Plus interface (sqlplus from the command line):

```
variable asdf number;
exec :asdf := 10;
select :asdf from dual;
```

Regards
K

Answer (score 1):

In SQL*Plus it's almost the same:

```
SQL> create table thetable (id) as select '01234' from dual union all select '12345' from dual
  2  /

Table created.

SQL> var id varchar2(10)
SQL> exec :id := '12345'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select *
  2  from theTable
  3  where id = :id
  4  /

ID
-----
12345

1 row selected.
```

or in PL/SQL:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_id varchar2(10) := '12345';
  3    r thetable%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5    select *
  6      into r
  7      from thetable
  8     where id = l_id
  9    ;
 10    dbms_output.put_line(r.id);
 11  end;
 12  /
12345

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way.

You have to declare it in a block (I think  it may have to be a stored procedure, or at least in a block).  However, that's only part of the problem.  Once it's in a block, the results no long "spill out" to a console window.  So you have to use a cursor, copy the row information into an array, and then step through the array printing the values using DMBS_OUTPUT.

It's easily enough to drive you back to MSSQL.

(note by Mark Harrison) This answer isn't correct... see the other answers for the oracle version of your code.

Comment: YIKES!  Every time I ask someone how to do something I can do with my eyes closed in MSSQL, I run into this kind of stuff.  You are right!  It is enough to drive me back.